# How explain these remarkable empirical observations about mod 3 modular forms of levels 1 and 5?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, recurrences, hecke-operators

Define $b(n)$ by $b(0)= 0$, $b(3n)= 9b(n)$, $b(3n+1)= 9b(n) + 1$, $b(3n+2)= 9b(n) + 3$. (This sequence does not show up in the OEIS, but the similar Moser-de Bruijn sequence [A000695](https://oeis.org/A000695) appears in many situations, one being the theory of mod 2 modular forms).

One seems to encounter the $b(n)$ when studying mod 3 modular forms of level $\Gamma_0 (N)$ for various small $N$. But what follows is largely empirical though supported by overwhelming evidence. I would welcome (but do not expect, particularly in the mysterious level 5 case) an explanation.

### LEVEL 1

Let $F$ in $\mathbf{Z}/3[[q]]$ be the mod 3 reduction of the level 1 weight 12 cusp form. Let $V$ be the subspace spanned by the $F^k$ with $(k,3)= 1$. The formal Hecke operator $T_2: \mathbf{Z}/3[[q]] \to\mathbf{Z}/3[[q]]$ stabilizes $V$. ($V$ is the space of level 1 mod 3 modular forms killed by $U_3$). Let $K$ be the kernel of $T_2: V\to V$, and $s(0) < s(1) < s(2) <\cdots$ the degrees (in $F$) of the (non-zero) elements of $K$ arranged in order of increasing size.

#### CONJECTURE 1:   $s(n)= 9b(n) + 1$.

This has been computer verified for $n < 54$; in particular $s(53)= 9019$. Here's how one makes the calculations. Let $A(n)$ in $\mathbf{Z}/3[F]$, $n$ prime to 3, be $T_2(F^n)$. The $A(n)$ satisfy the degree 9 recursion $A(n+9)= 2(F^9)A(n) + (F^3)A(n+3)$, with initial conditions $A(1)= 0$, $A(2)= F$, $A(4)= F^2$, $A(5)= F^4$, $A(7)= F^5$, $A(8)= F^7 + F^4$. This permits the rapid calculation of the $A(n)$ and of those $n$ for which $A(n)$ is a $\mathbf{Z}/3$-linear combination of $A(k)$ for $k < n$. These $n$ are the degrees of the elements of $K$.

### LEVEL 5

Let $v$ in $\mathbf{Z}/3[[q]]$ be the mod 3 reduction of the weight 4 cusp form of level $\Gamma_0 (5)$. Then $v(1) = v + v^3$ and $v(2)= v^2 - v^3$ are killed by $U_3$. Let $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbf{Z}/3[t]$ spanned by the $t^k$, $k$ prime to 3. Let $i: V\to \mathbf{Z}/3[[q]]$ be the $\mathbf{Z}/3$-linear imbedding taking $t^{3k+1}$ to $(v^{3k})v(1)$ and $t^{3k+2}$ to $(v^{3k})v(2)$. The identification of $i(V)$ with $V$ gives a degree function (degree in $t$) on $i(V)$. It can be shown that the $T_p$, when $p$ is other than 3 or 5, stabilize $i(V)$. ($i(V)$ is the space of mod 3 modular forms of level $\Gamma_0 (5)$ killed by $U_3$ and fixed by the mod 3 Fricke involution $W_5$). Let $K$ be the kernel of $(T_2 + I): i(V)\to i(V)$. Let $t(0) < t(1) < t(2) <\cdots$ be the degrees of the elements of $K$ arranged in order of increasing size.

#### CONJECTURE 2:  $t(2n)= 27b(n) + 1$ or $27b(n) + 2$ according as $b(n)$ is even or odd. $t(2n+1)= 27b(n) + 11$ or $27b(n) + 10$ according as $b(n)$ is even or odd.

#### CONJECTURE 3: The conjecture still holds when $K$ is replaced by the kernel of $T_7$.

#### CONJECTURE 4: The conjecture still holds when $K$ is replaced by the kernel of $T_{11} + I$.

All three of these conjectures hold for $n < 27$. In particular all three $t(53)$ are 7381. The recursions used to establish these results are messy; they are of degrees 12, 24, and 39 respectively.

Remark -- There is a similar computer supported conjecture in level 11 for the kernel of $(T_7 - I)$ acting on a space analogous to $i(V)$. But now $v$ is the reduction of the weight 2 cusp form of level $\Gamma_0 (11)$, $v(1)= v + v^3$ and $v(2)= v^2 + v^3 + v^6$.

Comment: Love your work, Prof. Monsky, but I really wish you'd take the time to learn how to format math on this site.

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting the question with LaTeX. I am not an expert in modular forms, so feel free to fix any errors I may have introduced.

Comment: I changed an incorrect plus sign in the remark to a minus sign. Suspect it was my error and not yours. Thanks for the excellent formatting. And this old dog apologizes to Gerry Myerson for my trouble in learning new tricks.

Comment: Its obvious but if we consider the base 3 representation of numbers then the function b replaces each digit as follows $0 \mapsto 00, 1 \mapsto 01, 2 \mapst 10$.

Comment: @user35593: Equivalently, replacing each digit 2 in the base-3 representation of $n$ with digit 3 yields the base-9 representation of $b(n)$.

Comment: The sequence $b(n)$ is now in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A319497).